# Why do I get LNK4098 conflicts with use of other libs - when trying to compile C++ in MSVS2010 Express?

Tags: c++, windows, linker, installation, visual-studio

My program will not successfully compile in /MT (MultiThreaded) mode. It Compiles in /MD (MultiThreaded DLL). I want to be able to use both libcurl and boost in an application I will distribute with an installer.

Compiling in: MSVS2010

This is code to replicate my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "curl/curl.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl;  
    curl = curl_easy_init();  
    return 0;
}
```

This is the warning I get if in /MD mode:

```
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; 
use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

If I try compiling in /MT mode I get:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in 

LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(realloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMT.lib(free.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtoul already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strtol.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMT.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in LIBCMT.lib(tolower.obj)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strtol.obj)
...
: fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I want to compile in /MT mode so that others can run my finished program with out having MSVS installed or needing to download anything additional. I can include and dll or lib files needed by my app in the installer.

I could disable loading the 'MSVCRTD' default library, but then compiling the with boost fails.

These are my preprocessor definitions:

```
WIN32
_DEBUG
_CONSOLE
BUILDING_LIBCURL
HTTP_ONLY
```

These are my additional dependencies:

```
libcurl.lib
ws2_32.lib
winmm.lib
wldap32.lib
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `nodefaultlib:libcmt.lib` in linker options in VC.

Comment: Now it compiles, but when I try to run it on a computer with out MSVS I get MSVCP100d.dll not found. What files do I need to include in the installation so that my program will not require the user to download any additional files?

Comment: ^ I have resolved the dll not found issue by including them in the installation.

Comment: Adding specific instructions would be an easy way to make this post more useful.

Comment: msvcp100[d].dll is not supposed to be distributed with the program. Note the "d" on the end, noting the "debug" version. Most users won't have the debug versions. 100 means MSVC runtimes 10 (from 2010; 110 is 2012 iirc). You'll need to compile in release and require the visual C++ runtimes for 2010 in order to run the app.

Answer (score 3):

MSVCRT**D**
LIBC**MT**.lib

flag compile the library differs from the flag compile the project (/MT,/MTD,/MD,/MDD)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `_DEBUG` from precompiler directives (i.e. build release version). The libraries you link into your application use a non-debug versions and your code links to debug-version. That's why you get linker error that symbols are multiply defined: it links both debug and non-debug versions of runtime libraries.

(As far as I understood you tried to statically link all the required libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

Try building libCurl with rtlibcfg=static. This will build the /Mt static version of libCURL.